# Ошибка: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = int(input())

while x > 0:
    y = x
    while y > 0:
        y -= 1
        print(y)
        x -= 1

print("stop")
```

Хочу получить цикл перечисления чисел

```
2
1
0
1
0
0
```

Можно немного переставить строчки и получить

```
3
2
1
2
1
1
```

Но не суть, у меня появляется ошибка, решения которой я не могу понять

Comment: если в x = int(input()) ввести не целое число, а строку, например, она не сможет преобразоваться в int, выдаст ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '

Comment: @Jack_oS, не там будет что-то в тексте ошибки, а у автора пустая строка, значит он ничего не ввел и нажал на Enter

Comment: @gil9red ок, пустая строка - тоже не преобразуется в int

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код рабочий. Судя по ошибке, вместо отправки числа - Вы нажимаете Enter.[image: Работа кода.]

Судя по тому, что Вы хотите получить, нужно:

```
x = int(input())

while x > 0:
    y = x
    while y > 0:
        y -= 1
        print(y)
    x -= 1

print("stop")
```

Comment: По сути всё рабочее, но при запуске, у меня просто ничего не происходил (нет ошибок, нет никакого текста, никаких цифр) 
Я нажимаю "enter" и появляется ошибка, которую я написал выше
У меня вопрос, мне нужно ждать, пока что то будет появляться или это с чем то связано?

Comment: При запуске программы введите в терминале число и нажмите Enter.

Comment: Ааааа....., понял
Огромная благодарность, помогли
Я только с лекции вернулся и решил попробовать, вот и сижу не понимаю))
Спасибо